# Is the beginning of a path enough in robots.txt?

Tags: robots.txt

I have the following files on my server:

```
/file
/file.html
/file/bob.html
```

I want to exclude them all from being indexed. Is the following robots.txt enough?

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /file
```

Or even just:

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /f
```

---

Note:

I understand that Google's bots would accept `/file` as disallowing them from all mentioned files (see https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt), but I don't want to address only Google but all well-behaved bots, so my question is about the original standard, not later extensions to it.

Comment: Is this just an example? Because it seems to me, the "trouble" and "expense" of just listing all 3 files and being sure would be quicker than the time taken in asking this question.

Comment: Damien, I want to understand. School was a lot of trouble, and it would have been quicker if they had just given me my exam right away, but they insisted that I actually learn to read and write, from which I have been profiting all my life.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, yes.

If you have:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /abc
```

It will block **anything** that starts with /abc, including:

```
/abc
/abc.html
/abc/def/ghi
/abcdefghi
/abc?x=123
```

This is part of the original robots.txt standard, and it applies to all robots that obey robots.txt.

The thing to remember about robots.txt is that it's deliberately not very sophisticated. It was designed to be simple and easy for crawlers to implement. Unless you use an extension (like wildcards) it's a simple string comparison. The directive will match any URL that starts with the sequence of characters you give.